# How can I set camera focused? ( I using ARCore with Unity3D )

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I am using Unity3d to create a ARCore Application on my android phone. 
I can make the app work well except focusing the camera. 
My question is how can i make the camera focused to a near object?
I can't find any configurations or settings in ARCore for camera.
Someone knows how to do this please help me .
thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARCore camera focus is locked at a value that the Google team has determined to be optimal for tracking. There are no plans to change that for v1 release.